# mongorestore and collection

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Hi when I do a mongorestore to dump my database `ok`

if I had:

```
> show dbs
local   (empty)
test    0.203125GB
```

it became:

```
> show dbs
local   (empty)
test    0.203125GB
ok          0.203125GB
```

but if I do a `db.getCollectionName()` it just prints

```
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "system.indexes", "test", "users" ]
```

I want ok to appear here, how can I do ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ok` will never appear in the list of collections, because `ok` is a database, not a collection. Databases contain many collections, but aren't collections themselves.

To see the collections in the `ok` database, type `use ok` followed by `db.getCollectionNames();`.

If you want to backup and restore a single collection, then you'll need to use the `--collection` arguments to mongodump and mongorestore. See [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools?focusedCommentId=5799964#ImportExportTools-mongodumpandmongorestore) for more info.